# Why android studio is showing this item in red

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm defining some resources in my code. As i'm typing it shows the required resource reference in code suggestion

[image]

However, once i select my option, it shows that reference in "red" and given message "cannot resolve symbol"

[image]

What's going on here ?

Comment: Have you tried `invalid cache and restart` android studio?

Answer (score 0):

**There are some reasons to show this item red**

1. Your project file is not properly bind with Android Studio.
2. Font processing not found
3. Project did not sync properly

**Here are some simple tips.**

1. File > sync project with Gradle file. [OR]
2. Check resources are available in your working module. [OR]
3. Delete build folder and and rebuild your project. [OR]
4. try invalidate cache and restart.